# How to change scale type

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Ive got problem with my single item activity, in my activity design everything looks good [image in design tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5MX14.png),but when I run the app image gets bigger in app [image in the app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQqTD.png)

Code for whole xml layout

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="175dp">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/container_org"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/screen_background_light_transparent"
    app:tint="@color/grey" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/item_org_logo"
    android:layout_width="110dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.48"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/eu" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/item_org_description"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="85dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:text="@string/eu_long_desc"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/item_org_logo"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/item_org_title" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/item_org_title"
    android:layout_width="249dp"
    android:layout_height="38dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:text="@string/eu2"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/item_org_logo"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/container_org" />
```

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

Comment: Share your item `xml` code.

Comment: its the image view, ive already shared it

Comment: But share your **whole** item xml code, including the right side `TextView`s.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the conflict between

```
app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.48"
```

and explicitly declared width:

```
android:layout_width="110dp"
```

You either have to remove `bias` attribute or change `width` attribute to `wrap_content` or `0dp`. I would recommend this edition:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="175dp">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/container_org"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/screen_background_light_transparent"
    app:tint="@color/grey" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/item_org_logo"
    android:layout_width="110dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/eu" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/item_org_description"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="85dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:text="@string/eu_long_desc"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/item_org_logo"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/item_org_title" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/item_org_title"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="38dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:text="@string/eu2"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/item_org_logo"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/container_org" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: yeah, ive got problem because when i use wrap content to attr width it goes max to the right

Comment: I added more details. Check and see if the problem is solved.

Comment: Ive copied ur whole xml and its still looks the same, nothing changed for me

Comment: Are the resources you use in circle shape by default? If not, how do you create a circle? Share the related code.

Comment: its png or jpg file with the logo of the company

Comment: even if I change scale type it only shows properly in design tab

Comment: I even tried making layout from the scratch with relative layout but it doesnt work as well.

Comment: You didn't read my comment carefully. I said: Are the resources you use in circle shape by default? If not, how do you create a circle? Share the related code.

Comment: sry, no some of the shapes are rectangular and square. I don't create circle its just png file

Comment: Ive resized every image to be 256 px wide